# Call of reflect.Value.Set on zero Value error

Tags: go, reflection

I am unable to assign a value to a pointer using `Elem().Set()`. I am getting an `call of reflect.Value.Set on zero Value error`. I checked the value that I am passing and saw that it isn't nil. I have worked on the same function before and it was working fine then. Is there anything that I am missing here?

```
outputInterfaceAlias := reflect.ValueOf(output)
fmt.Printf("kind: %+v\n", outputInterfaceAlias.Kind())
if outputInterfaceAlias.Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
    panic("Passed value in output interface must be of POINTER type")
}
val := reflect.ValueOf(asyncOutput)
fmt.Printf("value: %+v\n", val)
outputInterfaceAlias.Elem().Set(val)
```

The output I got was:

```
kind: ptr
value: map[value:[map[SUM:2.711528e+06 SUM(total):4909]]]
echo: http: panic serving [::1]:60153: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Set on zero Value
```

Comment: You can check with the `CanSet()` method. If I recall, you probably don't want that `Elem()` call in there.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear: Yeah, I am unable to set. How do I see that the value can be set?

Comment: You are printing the `val` variable, but it is the `outputInterfaceAlias` that is giving you the `zero Value` error.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear: i have made a sample case here and it seems to work just fine https://play.golang.org/p/a70FO70B_8

Comment: There has to be something else in your code at work here somewhere in code you haven't posted. I renamed a few variables and pasted your exact code snippet into your playground function and it works. https://play.golang.org/p/PeOT4yXLsB